# generate random phases between 0 and 2pi in excel

Tags: excel, random

i would like to know how to generate independently distributed phases between  0 and 2*pi in excel?i used this formula

```
=RANDBETWEEN(0,2*PI())
```

in matlab it can be  easily done

Angle = (2*pi) * rand(1,4) -to get 4 phase ,but what  about in excel?any help will be appreciated thanks in advance

Comment: It could help if you described what a "phase" is. Perhaps other users will know but I certainly don't.

Comment: sinusoidal component-amplitude,frequency and phase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Excel this should be

`=RAND() * PI() * 2`

Comment: thanks very much .in signal this parameter is involved or its degree